# Json data is not binding to jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

This is my first example with jQGrid ,I've written the following code .Grid is displayed but data is not bound.I've looked many examples but found no answer

**This is my Jquery Code**

```
jQuery("#jQGridDemo").jqGrid({
                            url: 'http://localhost:7887/application/get',
                            datatype: "json",
                            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                            page: 1,
                            loadonce: true,
                            gridView: true,
                            loadonce: true,

                            colNames: ['Application ID', 'Application Name', 'PageLink', 'CreatedDate'],
                            colModel: [
                                { name: 'ApplicationId', key: true, width: 75 },
                                { name: 'ApplicationName', width: 150 },
                                { name: 'PageLink', width: 150 },
                                { name: 'CreatedDate', width: 150 }

                            ],

                            width: 750,
                            height: 250,
                            rowNum: 20,
                            scroll: 1, // set the scroll property to 1 to enable paging with scrollbar - virtual loading of records
                            emptyrecords: 'Scroll to bottom to retrieve new page', // the message will be displayed at the bottom 
                        })
```

**I'm using web API 2 this is the c# code**

```
    [Route("get")]
    [HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage GetApplicationData()
{
    //string pno = Request.RequestUri.ToString();

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    FillDataSet(ref ds);

    DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
    var Jsonresponse = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt);
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, Jsonresponse);
}
```

**Reponse looks in the following format ..**

```
"[{\"ApplicationId\":1,\"ApplicationName\":\"Home\",\"PageLink\":\"~/web/Index.aspx\",\"CreatedDate\":\"2013-08-14T12:09:07.93\"},{\"ApplicationId\":2,\"ApplicationName\":\"Identify\",\"PageLink\":\"~/Web/Material/Home.aspx\",\"CreatedDate\":\"2013-08-14T12:09:07.93\"}........]"
```

Can any one tell me why this data is not bound to grid and pls suggest a few references to get learning for working with JQGrid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to do the following:

1. remove `http://localhost:7887` prefix from `url: 'http://localhost:7887/application/get'`. Corresponds to [Same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) you can't make Ajax requests per default to another source as the source of HTML page (no other server or other port). So it's better to use absolute paths `'/application/get'` or relative paths `'application/get'` in the URLs.
2. You should remove syntax error in your JavaScript code. For example the usage of `loadonce: true` **twice** is the syntax error.
3. JavaScript is case sensitive language. So you should be carefully in the case of all parameters which you use. For example there are no `gridView` option. You should use `gridview: true` instead.
4. I don't recommend you to use `scroll: 1` at least at the beginning. Virtual scrolling have many small problems and restrictions in the usage of other methods. Instead of that you can add the standard pager by using of `toppager: true` for example.
5. I would recommend you to use `height: "auto"` and `autoencode: true` options.
6. jqGrid has no `contentType` option. You mean probably `ajaxGridOptions: {contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'}`

Now I think you have problem in the server part of your code. If you use `datatype: "json"` then the HTTP request will have `Accept: application/json` in the HTTP header. So one uses typically something like `IEnumerable<Application>` as the result value of `GetApplicationData()`. The Web API 2 will convert the resulting object to JSON **automatically** based on `Accept: application/json`. If you makes **unneeded** manual translation to JSON then Web API 2 will suppose that the string (and not array of items) is the returned type of data. Corresponds to JSON standard all quotes `"` will be escaped. So the response contains **the string**

```json
"[{\"ApplicationId\":1,\"ApplicationName\":\"Home\",...}...]"
```

instead of

```json
[{"ApplicationId":1,"ApplicationName":"Home",...}...]
```

To fix the problem you should change the return type of `GetApplicationData()` and to remove unneeded manual call of `JsonConvert.SerializeObject`.

I recommend you to use [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or Developer Tools of IE/Chrome/Firefox (press <kbd>F12</kbd> to start) to trace HTTP traffic between the client and the server. It's very important for common understanding and for troubleshooting.

Comment: Thnk's i modified according to your comments and now I'm able to load the records into grid ,I've rectified errors and also previously i was returning json string but i modified .Now i'm sending json object and able to bind to the grid