# jQGrid not loading the next page records on scroll

Tags: jquery, ajax, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I'm implementing jQGrid.For the first time I'm able to get the ten records but what i want to bind another ten records when i scroll to the end.But this is not happening.Is anything I'm missing ,but i looked into the jQGrid site where exactly it has same setting(http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) under version 3.6 true scrolling rows

```
         jQuery("#jqgrid").jqGrid({
                        url: 'http://localhost:7887/application/get',
                        mtype:'GET',
                        datatype: "json",
                        colNames: ['Application ID', 'Application Name', 'PageLink', 'CreatedDate',"Rank"],
                        colModel: [
                            { name: 'ApplicationId', key: true, width: 75 },
                            { name: 'ApplicationName', width: 150 },
                            { name: 'PageLink', width: 150 },
                            { name: 'CreatedDate', width: 150 },
                            { name: 'RNK', width: 150 }

                        ],
                        rowNum: 10,
                        height: 180,
                        records: 1000,
                        rownumbers:true,
                        scroll: 1, 
                        viewrecords: true,
                        gridview: true,
                        caption:"Loading data while scrolling"
                    })
```

Below is the part of my  response data

```
{[
  {
    "ApplicationId": 1,
    "ApplicationName": "Home",
    "PageLink": "~/web/Index.aspx",
    "CreatedDate": "2013-08-14T12:09:07.93",
    "RNK": 1
  },
  {
    "ApplicationId": 2,
    "ApplicationName": "Land",
    "PageLink": "~/Web/Q1/Home.aspx",
    "CreatedDate": "2013-08-14T12:09:07.93",
    "RNK": 2
  },
  {
    "ApplicationId": 3,
    "ApplicationName": "Applications",
    "PageLink": "~/Web/Q2/Application/APL.aspx",
    "CreatedDate": "2013-08-14T12:09:07.93",
    "RNK": 3
  }
,.......10 records
]}
```

Comment: How many records **totally** exist in the database table from which you displays the data? The JSON which you included **contain only the 10 items**. Is it full JSON response or you inform jqGrid about the total number of records in the database?

Comment: It seems that you can already display first 10 records in the database. You posted [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29048583/315935) which is neither accepted or you posted any comment to it. If you want to get answers on your question you should communicate with the people who posted answers on your questions. You should understand that nobody want to spend his time if it's unneeded.

Comment: the total records is about 1000 ,but i want to load 10 records at a time (for each scroll end )...I've written records property as 1000 does it will not inform the grid about the total no of records to come ?

Comment: You wrote: "I've written records property as 1000". How exactly you did it? Do you mean the option `records: 1000`? Could you append the JSON response which you posted with the data. If you did it in a wrong way, it can explain your problem. Another thing: Do you tried to return *all 1000* rows, using `toppager: true, loadonce: true` **without `scroll: 1`**  and to measure the time of loading and the time of local paging or sorting? Which web browser is your main destination browser? Typically the usa

Comment: If you do need to implement **server side paging** then you should follow [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data#json_data) and return `total`, `page` and `records` in the JSON response. The items of main data should in the value of `rows` property. Without the information jqGrid will suppose that the data returned from the server are full data and the paging will be impossible.

Comment: Thanks @Oleg i was able to get the data on scrolling ,small doubt what is the use of property "total"  .... from the above properties you have meantioned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jqGrid supports *client side sorting* and *server side sorting*.

If your use `loadonce: true` then the server should return *all data* back to the grid. If the user click later on the column header, the data will be sorted *by jqGrid*. If you add the filter toolbar just by call of `filterToolbar` then you will provide the user the possibility to filter the data. No additional server code you need to write.

Your current code loads the page of data from the server and don't save any data locally (it saves the data only on the HTML page). So it's really important to understand that you have to implement sorting, paging and optionally filtering/searching of the data on the *server side*.

To implement server side paging you have to understand very clear the interface between the client and the server. Fisr of all you should remove `scroll: 1` and add `pager` or `toppager`. After that you will see in the grid the line (at the bottom or at the top of grid) like below

[image]

[The server response](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data#json_data) should contains three properties: `page`, `total` and `records` which will be placed on the pager. Other pager elements

[image]

allows to user to change the page size and to send request to the server about new page of data. If jqGrid displays the first page then the "First" and the "Previous" buttons are disabled. If jqGrid displays the last page the the "Next" and the "Last" buttons are disabled. **If the properties `page`, `total` and `records` are missing in the server response then all paging possibilities will be disabled** because jqGrid interpret the response as the only page of data.

If you use `scroll: 1` instead of `pager` or `toppager` then the user don't see the pager, but the paging is disabled because of the same reasons.